# How to add a scroll step size in on scroll function angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a function that executes whenever the user scrolls. This was done by using

```
($document).on('scroll',function(){});
```

The function displays images as the user scrolls. But it seems as if all the images were displayed at once. How can I slow down this process? Or can I add a scroll step size? That is something like,

```
($document).on(scrolling 10px, execute this function);
```

So that the function is called at 10px, 20px, 30px, etc.

Comment: you need to post the function code so we know what you did wrong.

Comment: the function works properly @fatman . It displays each image on scrolling down a pixel.

Comment: One option would be to use a variable that tracks the amount the user has scrolled, and when this threshold is reached, reset the variable to zero and execute the function.

Comment: @Jake259 exactly, that's why you should show the function – it has to be modified, like in a way proposed by Our_Benefactors. Also what you have posted so far doesn't seem to be related to angular.js – if so, please remove both the tag and the mention of angular in the title.